# Curl for loop writes previous loops value if there is no data in the current loop

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP CURL to collect some data but if one of the fields in my query is empty it writes the value from the previous loop, how can I correct this so that it enters no data if the value is not set?

```
<?php

    $domains = array( 'http://www.domain.com/' => '1',
              'http://www.domain2.com/'  => '2'
        );

    function file_get_contents_curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

    foreach ($domains as $url => $urlKey) {

    $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') {
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords') {
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }

    echo "Title: " . $title . "<br>";   
    echo "Description: " . $description . "<br>";   
    echo "Keywords: " . $keywords . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the data each time through the loop, as they're retaining their information from the last run through.

```
foreach ($domains as $url => $urlKey) {
    $title = '';
    $description = '';
    $keywords = '';
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you could put the information into an array so you only need to clear one item, something like

```
foreach ($domains as $url => $urlKey) {

    $site_data = array();
    ...

    $site_data['title'] = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    ...


    echo "Title: " . $site_data['title'] . "<br>";   
    echo "Description: " . $site_data['description'] . "<br>";   
    echo "Keywords: " . $site_data['keywords'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it now, the variables values are retained if they are not overwritten by the next loop, so one has to clear the value on the start of the next loop.